# Rotate small portion of an array by 90 degrees

Tags: python, numpy

I want to rotate an array but not as a whole, only small portion of it.

I have 512X512 array (basically it is a Gaussian circle at the center (150,150) with 200 radius). Now I want to rotate only small portion (center around (150,150) with radius 100) of the array by 90 degree. Initially I used numpy rot90 module but it rotate each array element which is not I want.

Comment: By array do you mean `numpy.array`?

Answer (score 6):

If you can describe the elements that you would like rotated using [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), then you should be able to perform the rotation using something like the following (assuming your array is called `arr`):

```
arr[rs:re,cs:ce] = np.rot90(np.copy(arr[rs:re,cs:ce]))
```

Here `rs`, `re`, `cs`, and `ce` would signify the row-start and row-end of a slice, and the column-start and column-end of a slice, respectively.

Here is an example of why the `np.copy` call is necessary (at least in numpy 1.3.0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = np.array([[i]*4 for i in range(4)])
>>> m
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])
>>> m[1:3,1:3] = np.rot90(m[1:3,1:3])     # rotate middle 2x2
>>> m
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],     # got  1, 2  expected  1, 2  
       [2, 1, 1, 2],     #      1, 1            1, 2
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `np.copy`.

Comment: @ecatmur, maybe it isn't necessary in newer versions, I'm using 1.3.0 so that could easily be it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some fuller code that does as `F.J.` has already explained.

[image]

And here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

def circle(im, centre_x, centre_y, radius):
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:im.shape[0],0:im.shape[1]]
    return (grid_x-centre_x)**2 + (grid_y-centre_y)**2 < radius**2

centre_x, centre_y, radius = 150, 200, 100
x_slice = slice(centre_x - radius, centre_x + radius)
y_slice = slice(centre_y - radius, centre_y + radius)

im = scipy.misc.imread('1_tree.jpg')
rotated_square = np.rot90(im[x_slice,y_slice].copy())
im[circle(im, centre_x, centre_y,radius)] = rotated_square[circle(rotated_square,
                                                         radius, radius, radius)]
scipy.misc.imsave('sdffs.png',im)
```