# Rotating a specific area of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an NxN matrix and I want to pick a specific part of this matrix and rotate that area by 90 degrees clockwise. I have to specify this rotation under these conditions:

- (a, b) position as upper left corner,
- (a + c, b + c) position as lower right corner, and
- whose side length is c + 1.

So, when I give a=2, b=3, and c=3, the output will be like this:

[image: example]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
N = int(input())
S = int(input())
arr = np.array(range(0,N*N))
arr.shape = N,N
for i in range(S):
    a,b,c = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
arr[a:a+c+1,b:b+c+1] = np.rot90(arr[a:a+c+1,b:b+c+1], axes=(1,0))
print(arr);
```

Comment: this will help [rotate small portion of an array by 90 degree in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086557/rotate-small-portion-of-an-array-by-90-degree-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

A 90-degree clockwise rotation corresponds to a vertical flip followed by a transpose. So:

```
def rotate_clockwise(x):
    return x[::-1].T
```

To use it on a particular region:

```
arr[a:a+s, b:b+s] = rotate_clockwise(arr[a:a+s, b:b+s])
```

In your case, `s = c + 2`.

---

EDIT: Perhaps even better is to use `np.rot90`:

```
def rotate_clockwise(x):
    return np.rot90(x, 3)
```

Comment: I solved it! deadshot's comment helped me but thank you all. I had to manipulate this part of the code as this:

arr[a-1:a+c,b-1:b+c] = np.rot90(arr[a-1:a+c,b-1:b+c], axes=(1,0))